# Having trouble receiving SMS on app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I followed a tutorial to receive sms and show it on my app. However when I tried to send sms using Android Device Monitor(and also telnet using android terminal), the emulator itself receives the SMS but the app does nothing.

The code is as follows...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Sms extends Activity {

TextView t1;
BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arr0, Intent arr1) {
            processReceive(arr0, arr1);
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

public void processReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] objArr = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    String sms = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage smsMsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) objArr[i]);

        String smsBody = smsMsg.getMessageBody();
        sms += smsBody;
    }
    t1.setText(sms);
}
}
```

The Manifest.xml is as follows...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Sms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any suggestions? The emulator receives the sms but not the app. I also tried using the android:priority attribute in the intent-filter tag but nothing works. The toast that is supposed to show "Incoming..." when the onReceive method is called is also not invoked (Indicating that the app does not receive SMS). The Permissions also look fine to me. Please help...

This is the Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-zYXVODiPo

Comment: What version of Android are you running under, and what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @MikeM. I am running it on Lollipop and it is also the targetSdkVersion

Comment: Well, your code is fine for that version. Maybe a problem with the emulator? Do you have a device you can test it on?

Comment: Btw, you know that the way you've implemented this, your `Sms` Activity has to be running and on-screen when you receive the SMS, yeah?

Comment: @MikeM. Actually, that's what I am trying to do. This activity is going to be part of another app actually. I am kind of "off shoring" this activity and testing it on its own so that I can integrate it later on

Comment: Cool. Then, yeah, as long as you're sure about the version numbers, and your Activity is in the foreground when you receive the message, then I would have to say that it's a problem with the emulator. I'll copy/paste your code, and test it to confirm.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the help there!

Comment: No problem. I just tested it on my device, and it works as expected. If you can, try it out on an actual device.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for testing it out. Yeah, I will test it on a real device then. I'll have to borrow someone's...Mine is on roaming. That's why I hesitated testing it on mine.

Comment: Gotcha. Give it a shot, when you get a chance, and lemme know if it's still giving you problems. Btw, make sure the device you test it on is not running Marshmallow. Good luck. Cheers!

Comment: It's now working on the real device @MikeM. Thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: No problem. I would mention that it's probably better if you move the `registerReceiver()` call to the Activity's `onResume()` method, and move `unregisterReceiver()` to `onPause()`. There's no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will get called, and it'll leak that Receiver if it doesn't. Also, a paused Activity can't really do anything, so it's best to not have that Receiver registered while it is. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. I would like to move the discussion to my new question,Show location stated in SMS on Map. I have already posted this. Just google it. Pls help me with that....

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this code to receive sms -

 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
                 SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                 String msg_from;
                 if (bundle != null)
                 {
                     //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                     try{
                             Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                             msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                             for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                             msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                             msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                             String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                       }catch(Exception e)
                       {
                       }

                  }
```